# Find a tax value for given amount with list of range

Tags: java, sql, data-structures

I have a list of ranges with tax

- Tax is 5% if amount is > 500
- Tax is 7% if amount is > 2000
- Tax is 9% if amount is > 5000
- Tax is 10% if amount is > 7000
- Tax is 15% if amount is > 10000

How do I store this in SQL table and retrieve for a given amount,

That is if amount is 2500 then tax should be 7%, I don't want to write a if else if statement to find the tax, any other best  solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`NavigableMap<Integer, Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/NavigableMap.html) (it's implementation is `TreeMap`)
The keys in this map are ordered. this allows for method `ceilingEntry(key)` which will return the entry with least key that is equal or greater then provided value. So you put the upper limit of each step as key and percentage as value

```
NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> taxMap = new TreeMap<>();
taxMap.put(500, 5);
taxMap.put(2000, 7);
System.out.println(taxMap.ceilingEntry(10).getValue());  // returns 5
System.out.println(taxMap.ceilingEntry(1000).getValue());  // returns 7
```

Answer (score 0):

you can save your data into SQL database as this format

[image]